# Помощь с Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, gui

Здравствуйте, постараюсь кратко: 
Я достаточно неплохо знаком с Джавой, но возникла проблема с построением пользовательского интерфейса, нужен удобный GUI designer, что-то вроде такого как в Net-Beans но для **IDEA**. В встроенном при построение все едет, нужен десигнер со сохранением отступов и размеров елементов.

Заранее спасибо, если что впервые задаю вопрос на стаке))

Screens:

Создаю:
[image: То что я создаю]

Получаю:

[image: То что получаю]

Comment: в каком смысле все едет?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman  становятся стандартные размеры, пустое пространство убирается, и получается все рядом

Comment: попробуйте добавить картинок, а то сейчас не понятно, что вы имеете в виду. для разных Layout Manager можно использовать разные механизмы для сохранения пустого пространства между компонентами

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил скрины

Comment: что именно вас не устраивает в результате?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman например нужно задать точное позиционирование кнопки, реальная задача - создать достаточно сложный GUI, я бы хотел найти десигнер, вроде как в windows forms

Comment: вы можете такое сделать. вот например кнопка по центру https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEvFx.png

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо, суть я понял)) просто с gui работал только в Андроиде и в WinForms)

Comment: создать сложный UI можно, но придется немного потренироваться и изучить компоненты.

Comment: посмотрите на JavaFX там есть отдельный Scene Builder - возможно он вам больше понравится.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman попробовал FX, думаю это идеально решение для меня)) огромное спасибо)), если хотите добавьте ответом, я подтвержу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете начать использовать библиотеку [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm). Специально для этой библиотеки написан редактор форм - [JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html). Он позволяет создавать формы различной сложности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]